# convex functions, is it enough to check if convex on all intervals

Tags: convex-analysis, definition

Let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be some function defined on a convex set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Now assume that for all $x \in X$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x+ty \in X$ for all $t \in [0,1]$, the function $f(x+ty)$ is a convex function on $[0,1]$. Does that mean $f$ is convex? To me the standard definition of convexity reduces to the case of intervals anyway, so intuitively my statement seems equivalent to $f$ being convex, but I don't see an argument why the definitions are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does.  The usual definition is that $f$ is convex if for all $u, v \in X$ and $0 \le s \le 1$, $$f(su + (1-s) v) \le s f(u) + (1-s) f(v)$$
That is true (for any given $u$ and $v$) if the function $t \mapsto f(u + t (v - u))$ is convex on $[0,1]$.

Comment: The choice of $v-u$ as direction is clear to me, but I still don't see how the inequality from the usual definition follows.

Comment: If $g(t) = f(u + t (v-u)) = f((1-t) u + t v)$, then $f(su + (1-s) v) = g(1-s)$, and
$s f(u) + (1-s) f(v) = s g(0) + (1-s) g(1)$.